# Why does my use state does not update even after using prevState? Is useEffect the only way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand useState does not update instantly. Some of the tutorial videos on react shows use of callback function as a way to achieve the result for immediate update. I tried that but it doesnt seem working .attaching the sample code

```
import { useState } from "react";
const testComponent = () => {
    const [userInputs, setUserInputs] = useState({
        age: '',
        comments: ''
    })

    function commentInputHandler(event) {
        setUserInputs((prevState) => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                comments: event.target.value
            }
        })
        console.log(userInputs.comments)
    }
    render(
        <textarea onChange={commentInputHandler} className="form-control" required ></textarea>
    )
}
```

Comment: First thing I see - components should begin with an uppercase first letter.

Comment: State updates are generally batched and asynchronous, so you won't be able to immediately log the results. You could use `useEffect` to monitor the state changes: `useEffect(() => console.log(userInputs.comments), [userInputs.comments]);`

Comment: @and so what is the use of having the callback function? Does it have any role in updating the state immediately ?

Comment: Thanks @BrianThompson for noticing it ,it was a sample code and my interest was to know on the state behavior than capital letter :)

Comment: Inside the `commentInputHandler` callback, if you need the new state immediately, you already have it under `event.target.value`. Otherwise, the state itself will be up-to-date on the next render.

Comment: My point is that state updates _are not immediate_. All the callback does is pass in the last state, and then update the state with that information, and the new information. It doesn't stop it being async.